# Design an algorithm for the single-source shortest path problem

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, directed-graph

Suppose a directed graph G = (V, E) with potentially positive and negative edge lengths, but no negative cycles. Let s ∈ V be a given source vertex. How to design an algorithm for the single-source shortest path problem that runs in
time O k(|V | + |E|), if the shortest paths from s to any other vertex takes at most k edges, and we don't know what is k is.

Answer (score 0):

Here`s O(k(|V | + |E|)) approach:

1. We can use Bellman-Ford algorithm with some modifications
2. Create array D[] to store shortest path from node s to some node u
3. initially D[s]=0, and all other D[i]=+oo (infinity)
4. Now after we iterate throught all edges k times and relax them, D[u] holds shortest path value from node s to u after <=k edges
5. So if on some iteration we can't relax any edge, that means we have already reached iteration k+1 and we can terminate the algorithm because shortests paths won't improve

   Pseudocode:

   ```
      for each vertex v in vertices:  
          D[v] := +oo  

    D[s] = 0  
    lastRelaxation = 0  
       for i in [1,n]:  
       {  
        for each edge (u, v) with weight w in edges:  
              if D[u] + w < D[v]:  
                 {   
                 D[v] = D[u] + w  
                 lastRelaxation = i  
                 }  
        if lastRelaxation != i) break;
       }
   ```